# ¿Como sacar nombres y apellidos de una cadena de texto con espacios y guardalos en una lista en Python?

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando el procesamiento de unos archivos excel que poseen un formulario de datos laborales.

Actualmente estoy usando Pandas y obtengo listas para cada campo formado por 2 celdas.

El problema que me ocurre ahora es en cuanto a los datos de los hijos del trabajador, ya que, este puede tener mas de 1, y el formulario fue llenado usando espacios para separar dentro de una misma celda los nombres, por lo que obtengo lo siguiente:

```
['NOMBRE Y APELLIDO DE HIJOS:', 'MARIANA ROSALES                               YESENIA ROSALES']
```

Accedo a este de la siguiente forma:

```
dato_personal[1]
```

**Mi pregunta es:**

¿Existira alguna forma de cortar la cadena de texto de manera que quede
`["MARIANA", "ROSALES", "YESENIA", "ROSALES"]`, o incluso para 3 nombres y apellidos?

Seria algo como cortar en cada espacio, pero no se me ocurre la forma, encontre fue como cortar en una determinada ocurrencia:

```
posicion_de_corte = dato_personal[1].replace(" ", 'X', 2).find(" ")
primer_dato = dato_personal[1][:posicion_de_corte]
primer_dato_clean = primer_dato.strip()
```

Pero solo funciona bien para 2 dos nombres.

Y si utilizo un ciclo for, al buscar la ocurrencia de espacio aparece algo como:
`15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23`, que son todos los espacios en blanco

Comment: ¿`dato_personal[1].split()` es lo que buscas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Termine utilizando esta función:

```
def separar_en_lista(dato_personal, lista_datos_personales_sin_espacios):
        datos_separados_en_lista = dato_personal[1].split(" ")
        datos_separados_en_lista_sin_espacios = list(filter(None, datos_separados_en_lista))
        lista_datos_personales_sin_espacios[indice] = [
            dato_personal[0], datos_separados_en_lista_sin_espacios]
```

**Donde:**

1) **dato_personal** es la lista que contiene los dos valores de mi formulario (campo y valor).

2) **lista_datos_personales_sin_espacios** es mi lista principal la cual quiero recorrer.

**Ejemplo:**

```
dato_personal
[0] => ["NOMBRES Y APELLIDOS"]
[1] => ["YESENIA MORALES                            PEDRO PEREZ"]


separar_en_lista(dato_personal, lista_de_ejemplo)

dato_personal
[0] => ["NOMBRES Y APELLIDOS"]
[1] => ["YESENIA, MORALES, PEDRO, PEREZ"]
```

Comment: Te comento lo que le dije a Bryro. Usa `split()` sin parámetros en lugar de `split(" ")` y de ese modo te evitas que en los resultados haya cadenas vacías y no necesitas hacer el `filter`. Por otro lado la función que pones no está bien, pues la variable `indice` no está inicializada. Y la función no retorna nada...

Comment: Solo quise agregar la funcion para no copiar todos los bucles que utilizo antes, pero si gustas para mejorar la respuesta los agrego y modifico como me dicen

Answer (score 4):

puedes intentar con esto:

```
data = ['NOMBRE Y APELLIDO DE HIJOS:', 'MARIANA ROSALES                               YESENIA ROSALES']  
hijos = data[1].split()
hijos = [" ".join(x) for x in zip(hijos[::2], hijos[1::2])]
```

Comment: Si pones `cadena.split()`, sin parámetros, te toma cualquier secuencia de espacios como si fuera uno solo, de cara a dividir. Así te evitas el `strip()`. En cuanto a la list comprehension siguiente no se entiende para qué sirve, ni el usuario preguntaba eso. Un mero `data[1].split()` hace lo que él quería.

Comment: data[1].split() haria un split de todo dentro pero no crearia nombre y apellido
el resultado el script es ["MARIANA ROSALES","YESENIA ROSALES"]

Comment: sí lo entiendo, pero si relees la pregunta del usuario verás que simplemente pedía obtener la lista `["MARIANA", "ROSALES", "YESENIA", "ROSALES"]`

Comment: un plus por decirlo asi, y una forma mas simple de trabajarlo al final!

Comment: Vale, te doy el punto :-) Y te sugiero otra forma de hacer el paso final, más eficiente aunque más ilegible: `hijos = [" ".join(x) for x in zip(hijos[::2], hijos[1::2])]`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar usando la librería `re` de expresiones regulares para buscar patrones.

Por ejemplo:

`import re
data = ['NOMBRE Y APELLIDO DE HIJOS:', 'MARIANA ROSALES                               YESENIA ROSALES']

apellidos = re.split('\W+', data[1])`

Buscará y guardará en una lista de strings todas las cadenas con 1 ó más caracteres alfanuméricos.

El resultado es:

`apellidos = ['MARIANA', 'ROSALES', 'YESENIA', 'ROSALES']`